# Java - Wiremock - Multiple Components

Tags: java, junit, nullpointerexception, junit5, wiremock

I've been trying to get this guide to work from Wiremock's documentation:

https://wiremock.org/docs/junit-jupiter/ - *Advanced usage - programmatic*

As I want to be able to mock multiple hosts simultaneously (same host, unique ports for my local environment). But I don't want these @RegisterExtension to be located in my test classes, instead in separate files but in doing so JUnit doesn't pick them up and I can't figure out why. Am I going about it in the wrong way?

Test code:

```
public class MyTest{
   @Test
   public void testMe(){
      MyIntegration.mock();
   }
}

public MyIntegration{
   @RegisterExtension
   static WireMockExtension wiremock = WireMockExtension.newInstance(wireMockConfig().port(9000)).build();

   public static void mock(){
      var info = wiremock.getRuntimeInfo(); // wireMockServer is null
      wiremock.stubFor(...); // NPE
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JUnit Jupiter scans test classes for `@RegisterExtension` annotations and runs the lifecycle methods on the annotated objects, but it won't scan non-test classes, which is why the server isn't being started in your example.

You have two options:

1. Create a base class with the `WireMockExtension` instances in it, then make each test class extend this.
2. In your integration class, new up an instance of `WireMockServer`, then make sure you call the `start()` and `stop()` methods on it before/after your test cases.

My preference is usually 1) in this scenario.

Comment: Won't that spin up a server for each WireMockExtension used? I would very much prefer if it was only one instance and it was used between my integration classes.